# Rotation isn't working in iOS5 Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a storyboard app and the rotation works on iOS6 devices but when I run it on my iOS5 device it won't rotate. I have a View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller (so the Navigation Controller is the root view controller of the window) and I have the following methods overridden:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

     if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)){
        return YES;
     } else {
         return NO;
     }
}
```

I also have the 3 orientations allowed in my plist, and my deployment target is iOS5 with the base SDK iOS6 and autolayout is turned off, and ideas why this isnt working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment caused me to look closer.  It's because you have a capital 'R' in autorotation.

Change your method name to:
`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I put breakpoints inside all of those methods in my navigation controller when running on iOS6 and the app did break in those methods